# Правописание -Н- и -НН- в во всех частях речи, какие правила нужно знать, чтобы никогда не совершать ошибок?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

Желательно увидеть все правила, которые нужно знать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимые правила вы можете прочитать, например, в [Aкадемическом справочнике под редакцией Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=51#pp51) и в [Справочнике по орфографии и пунктуации. Розенталь. Д. Э](http://orthographia.ru/go.php?url=http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=44,2#pp44)